# Deleting/ abandoning ASP.NET session state server

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-management, session-state-server

I am learning about the State management in ASP.Net using sessions.
I have recently used out of proc ASP.Net session state server for storing my application's session  data. 
What I wish to know is what happens to a session in the asp.net session state server if it is Abandoned. How is the memory managed on the asp.net session state server's end.
The behavior that I have observed is as follows:
Initially before creating a session in my application I checked, through windows task manager, the memory being  consumed by the asp.net session state process. It was around 2300 KB.
Then I created a session in my application, serialized and added a lot of data to it, after which the asp.net session state process memory increased to about 4700 KB.
Now I tried removing, clearing and abandoning(Session.Abandon()) the session but the memory consumed by asp.net session state process did not decrease, it stayed around 4300.
Can you tell me if there is any explicit memory management steps to be followed for out of proc sessions or am I missing any basic steps here.
How is this memory handled by asp.net session state process? If it is not how can I manage it?

Comment: The `Abandon` method does in fact instruct the state-server to release all references to the data, however the process is not under any obligation to immediately return that memory back to the host OS. Certainly it is more efficient to retain the memory allocation and reuse it for the next time something is stored in Session state.

Comment: I suggest you watch what happens to Session state server memory after storing the same object-graph again after removing it. My money says memory usage will remain below 5MB.

Comment: That said, session state should be mere *bytes* per user, certainly not megabytes' worth of data.

Comment: it does stay under 5 MB indeed. Thanks for the advice too.

Answer (score 0):

Once you don't have any more references (including the Session object) to your data, the garbage collector will clean it up.

This is non-deterministic, so you don't know when that will happen, but it will, eventually.

If it does never happen, then you probably have other references to the data somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt reply. I assume there is only a single reference to the session which is manipulated per request based on the session identifier, so session.Abandon should release the session. I think what Dai mentioned closely explains why I am facing  this issue.

Comment: Yes, Session.Abandon should release the references to the session state objects, however these objects may be referenced somewhere else and thus would never get garbage collected. This may or may not be the case, I don't know: the GC is a hard beast to understand, and it may actually take a long time before it kicks in and releases the memory (may even not do it at all, unless there's not enough free memory in the system for other things you are trying to allocate).